# Photos app on macOS not downloading new photos from iCloud

Tags: mac, icloud, photos, data-synchronization

I have the problem that the Photos app on macOS is not downloading photos taken with an iPhone. Sometimes it works and new photos appear soon after taking them, but most of the time it just says "Last Synced at *several hours ago*" in the bottom of the photos library.

I have verified that the Photos got uploaded to iCloud, and they do appear on icloud.com. It is on an Intel MacBook Air 2020, and the problem also appears when the battery if fully charged, it is connected to power, WiFi connection is stable, no other applications other than Photos are open. Both the Mac and iPhone are set up to sync with iCloud.

I have tried relaunching Photos, and logging in and out, rebooting, but it doesn't help. Usually the Photos only appear the next day.

In Terminal with the command `btctl log -w`, the following new output appears when opening Photos: It seems to concern the iCloud synchronization and shows several errors, but says nothing about Photos specifically.

```
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.469+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  Initializing BRAccountTokenWillChangeObserver with persona: __defaultPersonaID__
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.470+0200] bird[504]  ┏  received new XPC connection: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  welcome <private>!
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient checkinAskClientIfUsingUbiquity:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient queryPathsForPersona:reply:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.471+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.472+0200] bird[504]  ┃  <private>: reply(<private>, <private>, (null))
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.472+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.472+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  homeDirectory for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.473+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  mobileDocuments for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.473+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  cloudDocsAppSupport for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.473+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  cloudDocsCaches for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.473+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  documents for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.473+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  desktop for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.563+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  start monitoring provider info
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.563+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  add provider info change handler
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.563+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Creating new FPDaemonConnection connection.
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.563+0200] bird[504]  ┏  received new XPC connection: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  welcome <private>!
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient checkinAskClientIfUsingUbiquity:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient queryEligibleAccountDescriptorsWithReply:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.565+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  All logged in accounts cache populated to <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┃  <private>: reply(<private>, (null))
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.564+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.566+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  [ sending providerDomainsCompletionHandler: to FPDaemonConnection proxy on behalf of <private>[26760]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.566+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  New connection from pid 26760 [<private>]
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.566+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┏  ipc: <private> -[FPDXPCServicer providerDomainsCompletionHandler:]
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.566+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  <private>: returning 3 providers
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.566+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  ipc: <private>, reply of -[FPDXPCServicer providerDomainsCompletionHandler:] error: (null), domains: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.567+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.567+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default   o received reply from FPDaemonConnection proxy for providerDomainsCompletionHandler:
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.567+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  ┃  received 3 updated providers: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.568+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  ┃  Returning a domain for account: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.568+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  ┃  Returning a domain for account: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.568+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.577+0200] bird[504]  Session is nil or not open -- falling back to the account status
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.578+0200] bird[504]  <private>: reply(<private>, Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo={NSDescription=<private>})
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.578+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  fetched synced root URLs: <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.582+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Loaded module <private> from bundle <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.584+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Loaded module <private> from bundle <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.587+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Loaded module <private> from bundle <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.588+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Ignoring new world icloud drive override when fpfs is not enabled
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.588+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  Loaded 3 framework overrides modules.
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.597+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  ┏  getting primary iCloudAccount Status
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.597+0200] bird[504]  ┏  received new XPC connection: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.597+0200] bird[504]  ┃  welcome <private>!
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.597+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCTokenClient getPrimaryiCloudAccountStatus:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  current account is: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  iCloud Drive is disabled for <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account is not migrated to iCloud Drive <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  iCloud Desktop is disabled for <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Desktop sync is disabled for <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Documents sync is disabled for <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  account: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  checking status for <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  ┃  account status: <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  <private>: reply(<private>, (null))
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┏  Client <private> connection was invalidated
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.598+0200] bird[504]  ┃  ┏  invalidating connection with <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.599+0200] bird[504]  ┃  ┃  stop monitoring <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.600+0200] bird[504]  ┃  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.600+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.613+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  [ sending itemForURL:completionHandler: to FPDaemonConnection proxy on behalf of <private>[26760]
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.613+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┏  ipc: <private> -[FPDXPCServicer itemForURL:completionHandler:]
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  testing if <private> is in our 5 registered file providers: it's in <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  testing if <private> is in our 5 registered file providers: it's in <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  [ dispatching to <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default   o continuing on <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.614+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  -[FPDDomainExtensionBackend itemForURL:request:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.693+0200] fileproviderd[517]  ┃  notifying '<private>' on token 19 with state 0
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.693+0200] fileproviderd[517] clouddocs  ┃  <private>: request starting
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] fileproviderd[517]  ┃  notifying '<private>' on token 19 with state 0
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  [ sending itemForURL:completionHandler: to <private> on behalf of <private>[26760]
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┏  received a notif for <private> that [26760] became background
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.694+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┏  ipc: <private> -[FPXExtensionContext beginRequestWithDomain:alternateContentsDictionary:domainServicer:providerDomain:domainVersion:completionHandler:] <private>, 0
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  started extension: clouddocs
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┏  ipc: <private> -[FPXExtensionContext itemForURL:completionHandler:] <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  ┏  ipc: <private> -[FPXExtensionContext identifierForItemAtURL:completionHandler:] <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  ┃  [ dispatching to fpx-instance
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs   o continuing on fpx-instance
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.700+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  Initializing BRAccountTokenWillChangeObserver with persona: __defaultPersonaID__
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.702+0200] bird[504]  ┏  received new XPC connection: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.702+0200] bird[504]  ┃  welcome <private>!
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.702+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.702+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient checkinAskClientIfUsingUbiquity:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.702+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient queryPathsForPersona:reply:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.703+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] bird[504]  ┃  <private>: reply(<private>, <private>, (null))
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  homeDirectory for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  mobileDocuments for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  cloudDocsAppSupport for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  cloudDocsCaches for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.704+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  documents for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.705+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  desktop for persona __defaultPersonaID__: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┏  received new XPC connection: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┃  welcome <private>!
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┏  <private> (<private>) -[BRCXPCRegularIPCsClient checkinAskClientIfUsingUbiquity:]
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Account <private> is not loaded, waiting for it
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┃  Waited without success for <private>
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┃  After waiting, the sesion is: (null), handler is: (null)
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.706+0200] bird[504]  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.707+0200] bird[504]  Session is nil or not open -- falling back to the account status
[info 2023-06-13 21:36:39.707+0200] bird[504]  <private>: reply(<private>, Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo={NSDescription=<private>})
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.707+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762]  ┃  fetched synced root URLs: <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.707+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  ipc: <private>, reply of -[FPXExtensionContext identifierForItemAtURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (null), (null)
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.710+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┃  ipc: <private>, reply of -[FPXExtensionContext itemForURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.710+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] clouddocs  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] default   o received reply from <private> for itemForURL:completionHandler:
[ERR  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  can't get item for URL <private> for extension <private>; NSError: Cocoa 256 "<private>"
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┃  ipc: <private>, reply of -[FPDXPCServicer itemForURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] clouddocs  <private>: request finished
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default   o received reply from FPDaemonConnection proxy for itemForURL:completionHandler:
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] fileproviderd[517] clouddocs  Invalidating <private> because we don't have any inflight request or lifetime extender #lifetime
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:39.711+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  ┗  end
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:40.263+0200] com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[26760] default  remove provide info change handler
[WARN 2023-06-13 21:36:45.225+0200] fileproviderd[517] clouddocs  <private>: extension request grace timer ran out
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:45.225+0200] fileproviderd[517] clouddocs  Cancelling extension with request identifier <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:45.226+0200] fileproviderd[517] default  invalidating <private>
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:45.226+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] default  Cleanup of extension context <private> requested
[dbg  2023-06-13 21:36:45.231+0200] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[26762] default  <private>: invalidating
```

Is there anyway to force Photos to resync, or is there anything that could cause this problem.